# 403 Forbidden Error for video

Tags: javascript, html, http, video, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 error for a video hosted on a domain separate from my video player. When I go to the video link in Chrome, the video file plays without error, but when I add the link as the source of a video element in my page, I get an 403 Forbidden error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the video player code? Are you using an HTML video tag or proprietary video player?

Comment: Where is the video coming from? It may be a case of not being allowed to hotlink.

Comment: @ateich I'm using MediaElement player http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: Do you have this issue with other videos?

Comment: @ateich I do on desktop browsers (which leads me to believe it's a javascript problem) but works correctly on mobile browsers.

Comment: Is it a YouTube video? If so, the desktop browsers may be defaulting to a flash source, while the mobile browsers would most likely use an HTML5 compatible version. If not, you may want to post the video source or a JSFiddle, so we can dig deeper.

Comment: Fixed it. I was hotlinling the file from the other server so I updated the htaccess and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was advised to add the below to the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleRemoveById 950006
SecRuleRemoveById 950109
SecRuleRemoveById 950119
SecRuleRemoveById 950120
SecRuleRemoveById 950901
SecRuleRemoveById 950119
SecRuleRemoveById 958291
SecRuleRemoveById 960006
SecRuleRemoveById 960010
SecRuleRemoveById 960024
SecRuleRemoveById 960032
SecRuleRemoveById 960034
SecRuleRemoveById 960035
SecRuleRemoveById 960038
SecRuleRemoveById 973338
SecRuleRemoveById 981036
SecRuleRemoveById 981318
SecRuleRemoveById 981319
SecRuleRemoveById 981240
SecRuleRemoveById 981243
SecRuleRemoveById 981244
SecRuleRemoveById 981245
SecRuleRemoveById 981246
SecRuleRemoveById 981247
SecRuleRemoveById 981249
SecRuleRemoveById 981257
SecRuleRemoveById 981260
SecRuleRemoveById 981318
SecRuleRemoveById 981319
</IfModule>
```